# Permission denied on Netgear ReadyNAS duo

Tags: php, debian, file-permissions, netgear, readynas

This topic: http://www.readynas.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=53960

My Netgear ReadyNAS duo (it's a Debian box) is running PHP.

I wrote a script for organizing some files.
I succesfully read them from a directory /c/DIR1

Then I have to copy some of them into /c/DIR2

I get an error: Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: Permission denied in /c/website/Organizer.php on line XXX

My "/" structure:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 7168 Jun 10 10:38 aquota.group

-rw------- 1 root root 8192 Jun 10 10:38 aquota.user

drwxr-xr-x 4 admin admin 16384 May 25 09:57 home

drwxrwxrwx 3 admin admin 16384 Jun 9 17:29 DIR2

drwx------ 2 admin admin 16384 May 10 16:33 lost+found

drwxrwxrwx 3 admin admin 16384 Jun 9 14:52 DIR1

drwxrwxrwx 5 admin admin 16384 Jun 10 10:40 website
```

Obviously, running the organizer script command-line works.

What permissions do I have to set to my folders for making them 'more' writable by web-php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the folder permissions are the issue here. Try looking at the group; maybe your web-php doesn't have write permissions because of its group.

Comment: The group was ok.
My scripts run in /c/website.
Accessing in write mode to /c/DIR2 did result in permission denied.
Using ../DIR2 makes everything works.
Not sure about the reason but that's ok!